# Incorrect multicurrency Invoice - Odoo 15

Tags: odoo, odoo-11, invoice, odoo-15

I have multicurrency setup in odoo 15.  I  create the invoices in my local currency and i expect it to be converted into its dollar equivalent when I view the invoice in the invoice dashboard. Unfortunately it doesnt happen like that. When I create the invoice in my local currency, say a total amount of 5000, same amount appears in the invoice dashboard as $5000 but i expect it to be converted to its dollar equivalent  i.e: $666.7

Why does this happen and is there a way i could get this resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

Is the currency conversion rate configured?

Configure the currency rates in **Configuration ‣ Currencies.**

Refer the documentation: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/applications/finance/accounting/others/multicurrencies/exchange.html

Incase you have already configured the currency rate, check the date in currency conversion panel, there should be an entry on/before your invoice date.

Comment: Currency rate is configured and the currency conversion panel has the last date that a conversion rate was added

Comment: And most of those invoices are in draft